# Controls Webpage with Knockout: Visible changes not saved

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, knockout.js, dom-events

Trying to edit a website with Excel VBA. The edits appear to work, but when I use the save button, nothing is saved. Why isn't updated data, which is visible on the screen, being saved?

This code opens a web page in internet explorer, navigates where I want, fills out data, all which show on the screen, using various methods, such as:

```
For Each objElement In objElementColl
ExtractedName = objElement.outerHTML
        
If InStr(ExtractedName, "NewPermit") > 0 Then
objElement.Checked = True
```

and

```
Set DropDown = objHTML.getElementById("ProjectFile-AccreditedCertifierId")
DropDown.selectedIndex = 1
```

or

```
objHTML.getElementsByName(ElementName)(0).Value = ValueCheck
```

All work and changes appear on the screen. I click save by using:

```
Set objElementColl = objHTML.getElementsByClassName("btn")

For Each objElement In objElementColl
    ExtractedName = objElement.outerHTML
    
    If InStr(ExtractedName, "click: save, enable:") > 0 Then
        objElement.Click
        ExtractedName = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Which runs. The issue is it doesn't save the changes from the three pieces above.

What I have tried

1. Pause my code and manually click save (same issue)
2. Pause my code, manually change a checkbox and run the code to save (does save the manual change, but not the coded ones
3. Pause the code and manually change a box and manually save (only manually changed box is saved)

From above, it appears my save click works, but although the boxes are visibly changed and filled out using the code, there is a gap between the visible and the background.

Some HTML source code. Is what Chrome shows me when Inspecting an element I am changing:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Proposal</legend>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                    <label for="ProjectFile_ProposalLot">Lot</label><input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: ProjectFile().ProposalLot" maxlength="100" name="ProjectFile-ProposalLot" type="text" />
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group" data-bind="visible: ProjectFile().StateId() != 7 && ProjectFile().StateId() != 5">
                        <label data-bind="text: ProjectFile().ProposalDpLabel()"></label>
                        <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: ProjectFile().ProposalDp" maxlength="100" name="ProjectFile-ProposalDp" type="text" />
                        </div>
```

I searched the source code for the page. I believe this might be important, but I am not a HTML coder. I have shortened it a bit

```
var ProjectFileEditViewModel=(function(){__extends(ProjectFileEditViewModel,ViewModel.Model);function ProjectFileEditViewModel(){ProjectFileEditViewModel.__super__.constructor.apply(this,arguments);};ProjectFileEditViewModel.prototype.fields=function(){return {"Id":new ViewModel.NumberField(0),"StateId":new ViewModel.NumberField(0),"DefaultOfficeAddressId":new ViewModel.ObservableField(),"Name":new ViewModel.ObservableField(),"ExistingApprovalDate":new ViewModel.DateField("DD/MM/YYYY"),"ProjectClosed":new ViewModel.ObservableField(),"ProposalAddress":new ViewModel.ObservableChildField(exports.AddressViewModel,this),"Zoning":new ViewModel.ObservableField(),"ProposalLot":new return ProjectFileEditViewModel;})();if(exports.ProjectFileEditViewModel==null)exports.ProjectFileEditViewModel=ProjectFileEditViewModel;
```

There is also this:

```
Buildaform.model=new Buildaform.ProjectPageViewModel({ ... ,"ProposalLot":null .... }
```

I think this last one has something to do with it. I do not know if I can change it.

I cannot release the website address or source code publicly.

Comment: fair enough... will do

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to improve my chances?

Comment: I suspect it is not a vba issue but rather a HTML issue.... I don't know enough about it, maybe might be Java? Ill add those.

Edit: it limits you to 5 tags.

Comment: I've faced a similar issue on the past. 

Inspecting the html DOM with browser developer tools, I've identified that whenever I've manually changed a value on a form (lets say one with **id:input1**), it was 'mirrored' to another element on the DOM which was not visible (lets say one with **id:input1_value**).

Nevertheless, whenever I`ve changed the value of **input1** programatically, **input1_value** (which was the value used by the form) would not be changed.

The solution was to change both elements values programatically before submitting the form.

Comment: Ok, now we are getting somewhere.  How would I tell the second value?

Comment: Navigate to the web page, right click on one of the input fields and choose Inspect Element, this will show the DOM on developer tools. Now go back to the page and enter a value on the input, you shall notice a change on the related DOM element. Then, on the DOM view, search (Ctrl+f /Cmd+f) for the value you've entered on the input and check if it is found on more than one tag on the DOM.

Comment: So it is under the `Buildaform.model=new Buildaform.ProjectPageViewModel({` code, which I show above. Now I just need to work out how to edit that. Any ideas or website to point me to? 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know how to change it, but maybe some research on data-bind will help. This other question discuss it: [How to Implement DOM Data Binding in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript).

Comment: I assume you are getting an IE reference with `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`? How confident are you that all the javascript files referenced by the page actually load?

Comment: I use `Set objIEBCS = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` and

`Set objHTML = objIEBCS.document` 

In terms of the javascript, I really do not know enough about it to confirm yay or nay. I can personal message you some stuff if that is required

Comment: @BryanDavies - pretty sure your webpage is using the knockout framework (because of the `data-bind` attributes). Is there a bit of the HTML you can share that has an attribute like `data-bind="submit: doSomething"`? That is probably the key to understanding what automation instruction you need to code in VBA against the IE object.

Comment: Does this help?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/641604/HTML%20code.docx

Comment: @BryanDavies - gave it my best guess in answer below. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment that:

> 2. Pause my code, manually change a checkbox and run the code to save
>    (does save the manual change, but not the coded ones

It seems that the problem is with the code setting form controls and not with the code clicking the save button.

This seems to be a problem not related to **VBA** but with the behaviour of **knockout** - see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008283/programmatical-changes-will-not-reflect-in-knockout-viewmodel). The pertinent comment is:

> Your problem is that ko subscribes on the click event inside the checked binding:

The questioner in that post is having a similar problem to you -  they are trying to *check* a checkbox (to change the view) but it is not updating either the viewmodel, or the underlying model itself. Knockout is a [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) framework.

The give-away in your question is that your manual changes commit because you perform a click-and-change when performing the action via point-and-click in the browser, but your programmatic method only does the change to the form control, but not the click first.

So, how to solve this via VBA automation through IE?

Based on the solution in the post I referenced above, plus the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690571/fire-event-with-vba-internetexplorer-application-to-recalculate-jquery-form) I will hazard the code below as a possible solution, but please note it is untested ...

Basically you need to 'click' on the form element you want to change - and then update the control value. Hopefully the 'clicking' bit will mean that the knockout viewmodel updates per the 'change', and from there, the model data will be written to the database (or whatever):

Your checkbox example:

```
If InStr(ExtractedName, "NewPermit") > 0 Then
// hopefully this will get knockout to apply the required binding before your change the value
objElement.Click
objElement.Checked = True
```

Your dropdown example:

```
Set DropDown = objHTML.getElementById("ProjectFile-AccreditedCertifierId")
// hopefully this will get knockout to apply the required binding before your change the value
Dropdown.Click
DropDown.selectedIndex = 1
```

Hope that helps - quite the 3-pipe problem! Good luck.

Comment: Well... just as we are getting close to an answer, boss decided to change systems and I no longer need the answer.

I will however relook at this over the next weekend and report if it works. I have learnt a lot using this and it has been very interesting.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

As the regarding web site can not be shared, I can come up with a just set of hints to try out:

If the web site would implement a simple (pure) HTML form to send the POST request, your solution would be fine. But looking at the HTML you shared

```
<label data-bind="text: ProjectFile().ProposalDpLabel()"></label>
```

the `data-bind` is already suggesting that the data is getting collected/sent by a library. (E.g. [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) is using that attribute). This library might now collect the data somewhere, and it might get triggered by a "click" or a "key" event in JavaScript. The collected information can then be stored in a hidden DOM element as suggested by GCSDC or directly in a JavaScript variable.

What I would suggest now is to find out which JavaScript framework is used on this page by inspecting the HTML source. At some point there should be a

```
<script src="<fancy js framework>.js"></script>
```

tag in the HTML, which should give you the name of the framework. (There can actually be multiple tags of this kind, including custom JavaScript files. These tags do not have to be at the beginning of the HTML document, and can be scattered all over it, so you might have to search for `script` in the HTML document. One of them should be the main framework, which is sending the request. If you are not sure which one it would be, you have to google all of them and find out.)

Then, research how the the POST (maybe Ajax) request is sent in the JavaScript code on this page, with help from the documentation of the Framework. And then, send the request by executing custom JavaScript from VBA on this page; how this could be done is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228144/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-vba) post.

Alternatively, you could try to trigger a click (or key) event on the form inputs to make the framework believe you actually typed it in; how this could be done is shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247391/click-button-or-execute-javascript-function-with-vba), but this might not work in all cases.